# Lift RestHelper don't receive my request

Tags: scala, sbt, lift

I tried to create a simple `RestHelper` "Hello world" example but I'm having trouble. When I start my container with `container:start` command, the

```
serve {
    case Nil Get _ => Extraction.decompose("Hello Restful world!")
  }
```

is not invoked in my `RestHelper` extension. I get the following message: 
**"The Requested URL / was not found on this server"**

So, it seems that for some reason lift ignores

```
LiftRules.statelessDispatch.append(Service)
```

line in `bootstrap.Boot.boot` definition. And I have absolutely no clue why it happens.

Here's my `Boot` class:

```
package bootstrap

import net.liftweb.http.LiftRules
import com.yac.restfultest.Service

class Boot {
  def boot {
    LiftRules.statelessDispatch.append(Service)
  }
}
```

And here's `Service`:

```
package com.yac.restfultest

import net.liftweb.http.rest.RestHelper
import net.liftweb.json.Extraction

object Service extends RestHelper {

  serve {
    case Nil Get _ => Extraction.decompose("Hello Restful world!")
  }

}
```

and in case it helps here's my `web.xml`:

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app SYSTEM "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">
<web-app>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>LiftFilter</filter-name>
        <display-name>Lift Filter</display-name>
        <description>The Filter that intercepts Lift calls</description>
        <filter-class>net.liftweb.http.LiftFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>LiftFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

and in case all of the above is not enough here is my `build.sbt`:

```
name := "TestRest"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.6"

resolvers ++= Seq("snapshots" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots",
  "releases" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases"
)

jetty()

libraryDependencies ++= {

  val liftVersion = "2.6.2"

  Seq(
    "net.liftweb" %% "lift-webkit" % liftVersion % "compile"
  )

}
```

As you can see it's almost the most minimalistic lift project setup possible. Still I can't get it working. Any help would be appreciated.

And here's `sbt` log on `container:start`:

```
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /home/yac/IdeaProjects/TestRest/target/scala-2.11/classes...
[info] Packaging /home/yac/IdeaProjects/TestRest/target/scala-2.11/testrest_2.11-1.0.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[info] starting server ...
[success] Total time: 2 s, completed Apr 22, 2015 7:51:25 PM
> 2015-04-22 19:51:25.640:INFO::main: Logging initialized @44ms
2015-04-22 19:51:25.646:INFO:oejr.Runner:main: Runner
2015-04-22 19:51:25.726:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.2.1.v20140609
2015-04-22 19:51:29.818:WARN:oeja.AnnotationConfiguration:main: ServletContainerInitializers: detected. Class hierarchy: empty
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
2015-04-22 19:51:30.405:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@32e377c7{/,file:/home/yac/IdeaProjects/TestRest/target/webapp/,AVAILABLE}{file:/home/yac/IdeaProjects/TestRest/target/webapp/}
2015-04-22 19:51:30.406:WARN:oejsh.RequestLogHandler:main: !RequestLog
2015-04-22 19:51:30.417:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@7a601e4{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8080}
2015-04-22 19:51:30.418:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @4848ms
```

Comment: have you tried making the match: `"index" :: Nil` instead of simply `Nil`?

Comment: I even tried to set the routing as "test" :: "item" :: Nil. Still no use.

Answer (score 0):

So, turns out it's a usual noobish non-attentiveness. The package, containing `Boot.scala` should be called `bootstrap.liftweb` and not just `bootstrap` as in my case.

And yes, as suggested by **jcern** it should be `"index" :: Nil` in routing pattern.